# COMMA shift/reduce error bison

Tags: bison

```
A: constant
 | OPENINGBRACES B C 
;

constant: INTEGER | REAL | CHARACTER ;

C: CLOSINGBRACES
 | COMMA CLOSINGBRACES
;

B: A
 | A COMMA B 
;
```

this grammer is producing shift/reduce error.after running it with -v option it shows conflict in state 7 ..

```
**
state 7

8 B: A .
9  | A . COMMA B

COMMA  shift, and go to state 10

COMMA     [reduce using rule 8 (B)]
$default  reduce using rule 8 (B)
**
```

rule 8 is
**8 B: A**

Answer (score 5):

A shift/reduce is a CONFLICT not an ERROR -- it tells you the grammar is not LALR(1), so the parser produced by bison may only recognize a subset of your language.  That may be a problem, or it might not be.

In your case, the problem comes from the fact that `C` has an optional `COMMA` before the `CLOSINGBRACES`, but the grammar needs to complete(reduce) the `B` before it can go ahead to parse the `C`.  So when you have an input like `{ INT , INT , }`, when it gets to the second `COMMA` it doesn't know whether it should reduce the `B` (completing the list), or shift the `COMMA` to get another `constant` to add to the list.  In this case it should reduce (because the `COMMA` shoud be part of the `C` rule), but it doesn't know that without two token lookahead to see the `}` after the `,`.

In this case, the default resolution of the shift/reduce conflict as shift means that the parser will always expect another value after the comma, so will end up parsing the language without the optional comma (as if the rule `C: COMMA CLOSINGBRACES` did not exist)

One easy way to fix this is to make your `B` rule left-recursive instead of right-recursive:

```
B: A
 | B COMMA A
;
```

This way a `B` is a valid prefix of a `B`, so the parser can always reduce a `B` and then add additional `A`s on to the end of it later (after shifting the COMMA and seeing what the next token is).

Comment: And with Bison you should _always_ use left recursion instead of right recursion, not only to avoid conflicts such as this, but also to ensure that the parser can operate with bounded stack space.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: *always* is too strong -- certainly you should prefer left recursion to right recursion if all else is equal, but sometimes right recursion simplifies things, and the parse stack space difference doesn't matter if you are allocating space for the entire list anyways.